# Simple (standalone) Java SOAP web service client from WSDL using Maven

Tags: java, web-services, maven-2, soap, wsdl

I'm looking to generate a simple standalone Java client which will make calls to a SOAP web service, given a wsdl.  When I say simple and standalone I mean that once I'm done I want to be able to do something like

```
import my.generated.nonsense;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Client client = new Client();
    client.getSomething();
}
```

I've had great time recently with Maven on some other projects and I want to keep that going, so would aim to use it here.  I don't want the tool to generate anything expect the classes that allow me to do the above.

Anyone done this recently and can recommend a ws library and Maven plugin?  Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at CXF and its Maven [plug in](http://www.opendocs.net/apache/cxf/2.0/maven-integration-and-plugin.html). CXF would generate code similar to yours (of course web services could fail and you should add exception handling). Have in mind though that SOAP web services is a complicated topic and simplicity in the generated code may not be always desirable. Generating a client with the default settings may not work for some clients. You would then need to tweak the configuration of the code generation and/or add code to handle it. CXF is good both for easy/default clients and more complicated ones.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend [SOAP UI](http://www.soapui.org/) for what you need to do. You do not need to write any code - you can call the web service from the soap UI client.

If you need to automate making soap calls you can use the maven plugin as part of your build/deploy process. More info about the maven plugin here:
http://www.soapui.org/Test-Automation/maven-2x.html

Comment: Is it required to write the SOAP message by hand?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: You give SoapUI the WSDL-file and it generates templates tor the messages. You only need to fill in the values you want to set in your request.