# Java Soap request to WSDL

Tags: java, url, soap, wsdl

I have a wsdl url as follows: (this is for test and publicable)

http://partnerportal.turkcell.com.tr/spgw/services/AuthenticationPort?wsdl

I would like to make request to this url via soap and get a response. How can I do that? Where should I look for it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can also have a look at the [Java API for WSDL](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=110) or at this other [so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373350/simple-standalone-java-soap-web-service-client-from-wsdl-using-maven).

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a web service client. Here's a [tutorial](http://javapapers.com/web-service/soap-web-service-introduction/) for creating a java-based client using Eclipse.